# How to run PowerShell task with admin privileges in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to create RamDisk in DevOps agent servers using PowerShell task from Pipeline. The script can create the Ramdisk rive but unable to format and mount it. Its giving error that it needs elevated prompt.
How I can run PowerShell task with admin privileges in Azure DevOps pipeline

Comment: Is my reply helpful? Is your issue solved?

Comment: Any update and find solution for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you add `azure-devops-self-hosted-agent` tag, I assume you are using a self-hosted build agent for build. Then you can try to update the build agent to run with an administrator account.

> If you configured the agent to run as a service, it starts
> automatically. You can view and control the agent running status from
> the services snap-in. Run `services.msc` and look for the agent. If
> you need to change the agent's logon account, don't do it from the
> Services snap-in. Instead, try to re-configure the agent and run it
> with an administrator account.

Comment: This does not work, the agent runs using an Administrator account however it does not run the commands in an elevated terminal, resulting in an access denied error anyways.

Comment: How to run command with elevated terminal? I think it is irrelevant from service user, it is about running elevated terminal without any popup and silently.

Comment: I've not found a way to achieve this for exactly the reason that @alessandrocb mentions . Instead we will be trying to use the RunAs module to install modules as CurrentUser mode for all the accounts that we need them in. This way you can automate the install with ADO pipeines. Otherwise you are back to installing / upgrading by hand which is not my idea of fun.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have created Service Account with full admin privileges on my self-hosted agent
2. I have added the self-hosted agent to the Azure DevOps pool and configured it using this Service Account
3. All my tasks are running with admin privileges

My suggestion would be to configure the self-hosted agent using your Administration Account